# Prevent Android Notification bringing PendingIntent Activity to front

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I want to prevent a notification from interrupting the UX while busy on another activity.

[image]

When the user is busy with `Activity 2` and the notification comes in, the `Main Activity` is brought to the front.

I would prefer if the notification is just ignored/removed.

### Notification Code:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
notificationIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 99, notificationIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

var builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
//builder.SetAutoCancel(false);
//builder.SetTicker("notification");
builder.SetContentTitle(title); //title parameter
builder.SetContentText(subtitle); //subtitle parameter
builder.SetStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().BigText(body)); //body parameter
builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification_icon);
//builder.SetLargeIcon();
builder.SetContentIntent(contentIntent);
//builder.SetOngoing(false);
builder.SetColor(color); //color parameter
builder.SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);
builder.SetLights(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue, 1500, 1000);

var notifyManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);

notifyManager.Notify(id, builder.Build()); //id parameter
```

How I move from `Main Activity` to `Activity 2`:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity2));
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
StartActivity(intent);
Finish();
```

and back to `Main Activity`:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
StartActivity(intent);
Finish();
```

As you can see, the activities run independently only one at a time.

Comment: Dont fire activity in pending intent but a receiver. When notification clicked you will get event in receiver.
In activity store instance in variable and nullify when activity is stopped or destroy so you can check this instance in receiver. when instance is not null means activity(Activity1 or Activity2) is running so dont start MainActivity otherwise start MainActivity

Comment: Thank you. I did this and works.